# How do I use Javascript in my Coldfusion page?

Tags: javascript, coldfusion

I have a coldfusion page and I am very newbie in coldfusion. What I need to do is to insert the alert in between to see what is the time. In php I could close the php tags and enter the javascript tag and alert out the value. How would I do that in coldfusion? I have this

```
<cfset right_now=Now()> 
        <cfscript>
    alert(#right_now#);
    </cfscript>
```

But its not working.
thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[`<cfscript>`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7ebf.html) is a Coldfusion tag for using the [Coldfusion scripting language](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7feb.html) (aka CFScript). If you want to use Javascript, open a `<script>` tag like you would normally in HTML. You'll probably want to make sure it's inside a [`<cfoutput>`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7ff6.html) tag if you want to use Coldfusion values within your javascript.

```
<cfset right_now = Now()>

<cfoutput>
<script type="text/javascript">
  alert('#right_now#'); // don't forget you need to put quotes around strings in JS
</script>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Also remember `JsStringformat` to correctly escape strings! A timestamp has single quotes in itself, which will cause errors. like that.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to even use cfscript for this specific need. You could, for instance, do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var currtime = new Date();
     alert(currtime);
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

... Also a point to remember, you can't directly output HTML from within a `<cfscript>` tag.  You can however get around this by calling a function from within a `<cfscript>` tag that can output the data for you.

Comment: WriteOutput() being the function

Answer (score 2):

Always remember the coldfusion begins and ends before *anything* else is executed: html, javaScript, sql, etc., so the javascript is getting an already formed code, which is CF instead of being hard coded.